# Plumbing: Two control points for shower

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, shower

I'm doing a remodel and I wanted to ask for your advice.

I have a fairly large shower spanning the entire width of the bathroom (see the plan below). I'd like to set up the showerhead at one end of the shower (the furthest point from the 5'6" unmovable glass door) - but I worry that with that plan, I won't be able to turn the shower on without getting wet before the water warms up.

What I would like to do ideally is to have the showerhead where it is on the plan, have the mixer right there, but *add a secondary set of flow controls* where the red arrow is on the plan. Is that possible? Is it crazy? What kind of equipment would I need to add to make that happen?

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: Why not just have it on the side that doesn't get you wet??

Comment: OT - Are you sure that a puny little 50 CFM fan for that large of bathroom is even close to adequate? From the chart here: http://www.efi.org/factoids/bathroom_sizing.html it is clear that for an average equivalent duct length you should be planning for a 150 CFM fan.

Comment: As @DMoore says: if you have a good thermostatic mixer, how often do you need to change it while you are showering? Or is it one with extra functionality (multiple showerheads etc)?

Comment: Perhaps if such a thing exists just get a valve that diverts the water from the shower to the drain when the temperature is below the set point on the valve.

Comment: A less expensive option to two sets of controls is to install the type of fixture that is usually used to fill a tub.  Turn on the water (to hot) with the water coming out of that fixture.  Once it is hot, lower the temperature and then pull the handle to get the water coming out of the shower head.  I do all that while standing in the shower to minimize wasted water.

Comment: As an alternative to @RockPaperLizard's suggestion: Have both a wall-mounted and handheld nozzle. (Or a handheld with a wall bracket.) Switch to handheld, point it at wall, adjust temp and pressure before switching back or remounting it. Outside of that: Unless you're going to have nozzles at both ends, or are planning for wheelchair users, I don't see much point in a shower enclosure that size. Most of it will go unused. If you were doing shower plus tub the length of the tub would require that space, but...?

Comment: To give an update for everyone: I did end up implementing the on/off valve as described on the diagram, running the piping to that valve and back. It works fine for a few years now. No issues.

Comment: can you route a pipe after the mixer and before the diverter to a single lever on off valve outside the shower door for turning on the water?

Answer (score 1):

Sure I think you could do this.  You'd need another set of supply lines at the other side, and a second valve.  You'd then run the pipe for the shower head to the other side of the shower and T it in with the other shower head pipe.

The only downside I can think of is the cost - a good thermostatic valve is expensive!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you really need is a remote controlled shower valve and temperature controller. Most major manufacturers are offering these now including the likes of Kohler, Moen and others. These give you remote digital control of your shower including temperature, timer mode, warm up mode and flow rate control.

If you're not prepared for the relatively high cost of these systems then I guess you will just decide to get all wet.

[image]  [image]

Answer (score 1):

Simple (and cheap) method would be to install the mixing valve set of your choice for the wall with the shower head and install two simple control valves upstream of the mixing valve unit, one for hot and one for cold. You could leave the mixer set at the temperature and flow rate that you normally use, the upstream valves would basically be remote shut-offs to be opened fully when preparing to shower.
[image]