# Plumbing: Dual volume control valve WITHOUT mixing

Tags: plumbing

This is probably a total newbie question, I apologize in advance.

I have two pipes, hot and cold; I'd like to set up a single control point that turns the flow on both of them on or off, at the same time. I've been scouring the internet but I just can't find it.

Requirements:

- I don't want a thermostatic mixing valve - I need the output to still be two pipes, hot and cold.
- I don't want two knobs. Two knobs would be an easy solution but not the one I need cosmetically.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to setup?  That is a fairly odd configuration, it would be helpful to know why you want it that way.

Comment: Clearly this is related to your [other question](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/53064/plumbing-two-control-points-for-shower)

Comment: I've certainly never heard of a valve that has two separate in/outs like you're describing. However, I am thinking about this being possible using solenoids.. but safety is an issue.

Answer (score 7):

Laundry Shut-off valve - any hardware/plumbing store or the internet.

[image: Valve image from home depot, just as an example.]

Comment: Of course, it might be nice to find a version which is designed to be plumbed in on both sides rather than having hose threads. Then again, I suspect that someone makes an adapter you could solder onto the threaded end to covert it back to a soldered connection. "If it happens, it must be possible."

Answer (score 0):

Never heard of such a thing.  But off the top of my head, you could mechanically link two hidden conventional spigots.  I'm imagining a faucet handle connected by a shaft to a conventional toothed gear.  That gear is meshed to two additional gears each of which is connected to a spigot.  Turning the one faucet Handle then operates two spigots.  Far from off the shelf and may be a pain, but should work in principle.

Answer (score 0):

That is just a shut-off valve.